# Prove that $\sum(\sum (t_i-t_j)^2x_ix_j)\le0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Given are the real numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ and $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$ for which holds: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$.
> Prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=1}^n (t_i-t_j)^2x_ix_j \right)\le 0.$$
> Source: [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1068820t243f1068820h3003616_double_sum_t_it_j2x_ix_j_lt_0_if_sum_x_i__0) (unsolved)

I bashed $n=3$ condition, but cannot proceed to larger $n$.

When $n=3$, the problem is equivalent to
\[(t_1-t_2)^2x_1x_2+(t_2-t_3)^2x_2x_3+(t_3-t_1)^2x_3x_1\le0.\tag1\]

Since
\[(x_1x_2t_1t_2)(x_2x_3t_2t_3)(x_3x_1t_3t_1)=(x_1x_2x_et_1t_2t_3)^2\ge0,\]
WLOG $x_2x_3t_2t_3\ge0$. Write $(1)$ as a quadratic of $t_1$,
\[t_1^2(x_1x_2+x_1x_3)-2t_1(t_2x_1x_2+t_3x_1x_3)+t_2^2x_1x_2+(t_2-t_3)^2x_2x_3+t_3^2x_1x_3\le0.\]
The coefficient of $t_1^2$ is $(x_2+x_3)(-x_2-x_3)\le0$, and the descriminant
\[\Delta=\cdots=-16x_2x_3t_2t_3\le0.\]
Done!

How to prove for generic $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just expand the square.

$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}  \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} t_i^{2}x_ix_j=0$ because $ \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_j=0$.

Similarly,

$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}  \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} t_j^{2}x_ix_j=0$.

Finally, $-2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}  \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} t_it_jx_ix_j=-2 (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}t_ix_i)^{2} \leq 0$.

Comment: Maybe you meant $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n$ for the second sum?

Comment: @youthdoo Yes, certainly. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

The hint.

Since $x_n=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i,$ we need to prove that:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(t_n-t_i)x_i\right)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Is it possible to make the square directly or did you also expand?

Comment: @youthdoo An expanding, of course. But it's very smooth because $t_i-t_j=t_i-t_n+t_n-t_j.$

Comment: But why did I compute the discriminant $\Delta\not\equiv0$? It is strange.

Comment: @youthdoo After substitution $x_n=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i$ should be $\Delta\equiv0$, but it's better to see that we got a full square.